# MissingPluginException('No implementation found for method $method on channel $name');

Tags: flutter, android-biometric-prompt, flutter-method-channel

I am creating flutter package , when I am testing on test project with direct call to android method it works, but when I am trying it with flutter package example project got this below error.

`MissingPluginException('No implementation found for method $method on channel $name');`

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: @pskink
`MissingPluginException('No implementation found for method $method on channel $name');`

got this error

Comment: yes, the problem is in your code

Comment: @pskink
https://github.com/Imesh7/pin_screen_biometric_authenticator this is the repo, can you check that out